# How to open http links in a secure iframe html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, href

I working on an application which uses https (secure) and I am using iframe to open a new portal in the application. As per apps requirement I need to open a url on http instead of the https and iframe does not allow it. so I am trying to add href tag in the iframe tag so that it can be done. I check and found that through pipes we can do this but I am unable to do so.

```
<div>
<p><a href= "http://serverip:5905/index.html?"  target="myIframe">Click Here  </a>
  Please click on the this to view the data</p>
```

this is my html page.

=============================

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { VisualizerService } from '../visualizer.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-visualizer',
templateUrl: './visualizer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./visualizer.component.css']
})

@Pipe({
name: 'safe'
})

export class VisualizerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, PipeTransform {

constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, public visualizerService: VisualizerService, public router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.visualizerService.getXpraServerDetails().subscribe(data => {
if (data['session']) {
return alert('session time out');
}

this.startVisualizer(data['userName'], data['password'], data['proxyPort'], data['host'], data['xpraServer']);

}, err => {
alert(err);
this.visualizerService.stopXpraServer().subscribe(data => { });
});
}

@ViewChildren('iframe') iframe;
iframeSrc;
test;

transform(url) {
return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

startVisualizer(userName, password, proxyPort, host, xpraClientServer) {

this.iframeSrc =  this.transform(xpraClientServer + "/?index.html"+ "&username=" + userName + "&password=" +password)
}
```

Please help me to correct this.

Comment: FYI, `href` is an _attribute_, and the iframe in which you're working is an _element_. Neither are tags in the context you're using.

Comment: Please format (indent) your code properly. Walls of text are harder to read.